# Cannot create VM on ESXI - insufficent space - but that doesn't seem true?

Tags: vmware, esxi

I have a ESXI Server with 211 Gigs free

[image]

Today I bought a Windows 10 license key and downloaded the ISO from Microsoft.  I created a VM of this directly on VMWare, turned that into a OVA and that I was able to upload to ESXI - Create VM From OVA file - no problems.

However, I wanted to learn how to make VM directly on the ESXI server.  I have uploaded the ISO Windows 10 install media onto the datastore.  I went to create a new VM - Windows - Windows 10.  I left the default settings of a 48 gig hard drive as this won't need a lot on it.  However I keep getting rejected from creating it -

```
State
Failed - Insufficient disk space on datastore 'datastore1'.

Errors
File system specific implementation of SetFileAttributes[file] failed
```

Tried a few times, lowering the hard drive on the customize settings down to 30 gigs but still could not.

I went back and tried creating it from the OVA again which has 100 gigabytes allocated as the hd space (though I do select "thin" during that creation) and that again worked fine.

What am I missing here, why can't I make this VM directly with the install ISO due to space, but I can use the OVA for the same exact VM with a larger hard drive and that seems to work fine?

EDIT 1: I only have 1 datastore, I went back to putting the OVA version on for now but see the following screen show - 195 GB free right onw.
[image]

Comment: are you sure the storage meter you are looking at is showing the datastore1 capacity, not the capacity on the disk that datastore1 is defined on?

Comment: Provide a screenshot of the storage capacity of datastore1.  This is necessary information required to answer your question.

Comment: Provided screenshot.  Am I misinterpreting the above?  It seems like I should have 195 GB available.

Comment: Suspect the difference is the thin provisioning. Within `/var/log/vpxa.log` do you see "An error occurred while taking a snapshot: There is not enough space on the file system for the selected operation."? What version of ESXi are you running exactly?